# Trying to strip a string

Tags: javascript, php, function

I'm using a a function in wordpress to call an id into a post and I want to strip that id from characters and allow only digits.

Here's the function from **functions.php**:

```
function myshortcode_imdbid( ){
   return dt_get_meta('ids');
}
add_shortcode( 'post_imdbid', 'myshortcode_imdbid' );
```

Using the shortcode `[post_imdbid]` it will print in a post an id like `tt3212121` and I want to strip those ids from the `tt` characters in the front.

Any idea on how should I do that?

Comment: is it always 'tt'

Comment: Yes, it is always, and if it is possible to modify that functions so I'll be able to call it thru the same shortcode...yet, if it is not possible any idea will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. 
One way to do it:

```
function myshortcode_imdbid( ){
   $id = dt_get_meta('ids');
   return trim($id, 't');
}
add_shortcode( 'post_imdbid', 'myshortcode_imdbid' );
```

Comment: Your idea worked. I wish to ask you something else, may I? Do you have a  skype or something where I can contact you?

Answer (score 0):

With PHP I would propose to do something like this:

```
substr($imdbid, 2);
```

Or:

```
trim($imdbid, 't');
```

Comment: Big thanks for your reply. Worked with the first option. Thanks anyway.